# Google stackdriver debug not working in Kubernetes

Tags: python-3.x, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

We have a server application based on Python 3.6 running on Google Kubernetes Engine. I added Google StackDriver Debug to aid in debugging some production issues but I cannot get our app to show up in the Stackdriver debug console. The 'application to debug' dropdown menu stays empty.

The kubernetes cluster is provisioned with the `cloud-debug` scope and the app starts up correctly. Also, the Stackdriver Debugging API is enabled on our project. When running the app locally on my machine, cloud debugging works as expected, but I cannot find a reason why it won't work on our production environment

Comment: Stackdriver Debug tool is intended for debugging application code. So it can't be used to debug Kubernetes directly, but it could be used to debug the applications in containers that are running in the cluster. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/) are the supported platforms [1] with GKE being in Beta already. You also need to give access to your cluster, so the tool can see it. To do that, please make sure the cluster is created with both [cloud-platform & cloud_debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/nodejs#gke) scopes enabled.

Comment: In case my question was unclear: we are debugging application code, not Kubernetes itself. As to the cluster access: the documentation seems to indicate that either cloud-platform or cloud-debugger scope is necessary: [https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/python#gke]

Comment: Please note the exact spelling for "cloud-platform" and "cloud_debugger" scope. If this solves the issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem was not with the scopes of the platform, but rather with the fact that you cannot simply `pip install google-python-cloud-debugger` on the official python-alpine docker images. Alpine Linux support is not tested regularly and my problem was related to missing symbols in the C-library. 
Alpine Linux uses the MUSL C-library and it needs a google cloud debugger specifically built for that library. After preparing a specific docker image for this, I got it to work with the provided credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative method, you can debug Python pods with Visual Studio code and good old [debugpy](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/)

[I wrote an open source tool that will inject debugpy into any running Python pod without prior setup.](https://docs.robusta.dev/master/catalog/actions/python-troubleshooting.html#python-debugger)

To use it, you'll need to:

1. Install the tool in your cluster (see [Github page](https://github.com/robusta-dev/robusta))
2. Run a command locally from a machine with access to the cluster:

```sh
robusta playbooks trigger python_debugger name=myapp namespace=default
```

3. Port-forward to the cluster (the tool prints instructions)
4. Attach VSCode to localhost and the port that you're forwarding

This works by creating a new pod on the same node and then injecting debugpy using [debug-toolkit](https://github.com/robusta-dev/debug-toolkit/)